# Override several controllers in one single module Magento

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

I need to override the following controllers

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php
```

In one single module that overrides the native checkout of Magento. Following's Inchoo's tutorial, I did this in my config.xml :

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mycompany_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">MyCompany_Checkout</mycompany_checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mycompany_checkout before="Mage_Customer">MyCompany_Checkout_AddressController</mycompany_checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And the code of my controller (Example of AddressController)

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AddressController.php');


class MyCompany_Customer_AddressController extends Mage_Customer_AddressController {
 // Overriden function ...
}
```

but it's not working.

Any clue on what I'm missing ?

Comment: Are you including the overridden controller path in the new one ?

Comment: Hey could you please paste here entire code that you did so i can help you with this

Comment: RabeeAbdelWahab Yes, sorry I didn't add my controller in my post

@sagarumaretiya Here you go. My objective is to have a controllers folder in my checkout module so that all override that were made because of the checkout stay in the checkout module.

Comment: @Laila please let me know if the below solution worked. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension I wrote as an example. it has been tested and working on all controllers overridden.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
        <modules>
                <Rabee3_Stackoverflow>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                </Rabee3_Stackoverflow>
        </modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <sales>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <stackoverflow before="Mage_Sales">Rabee3_Stackoverflow</stackoverflow>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </sales>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <stackoverflow before="Mage_Customer">Rabee3_Stackoverflow</stackoverflow>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Controllers to override, showing the required core file and also how it is extended:

AccountController.php

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php');
class Rabee3_Stackoverflow_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
```

AddressController.php

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AddressController.php');
class Rabee3_Stackoverflow_AddressController extends Mage_Customer_AddressController
{
```

OrderController.php

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Sales').DS.'OrderController.php');
class Rabee3_Stackoverflow_OrderController extends Mage_Sales_OrderController
{
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I just had to modify something in your answer, I had to write "MyCompany_Mymodule" in the declaration of the modules in the routers section (so rabee3_stackoverflow in your case instead of stackoverflow in the config.xml file).